# How to check for end of string in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am a noob, I am stuck on this code.

I am taking input from user in a textbox and saving it in a string. Then I want to run a loop until the string ends and I put if condition for different characters....

```
string que;
que = textBlock1.Text;
        while (!que[i].Equals('\0'))
        {
            int res;
            if (int.TryParse(que[i].ToString(), out res) || que[i].ToString() == "x" || que[i].ToString() == "/" || que[i].ToString() == "^")
            {
                f[j] = f[j] + que[i].ToString();
            }
            if (que[i].ToString() == "+" || que[i].ToString() == "-")
                j++;
            i++;

        }
```

Can someone please guide me? What should I do??

Comment: What is `f` and what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please try to give as much information as possible in order to get useful help.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
textBlock1.Text.Lenght
```

That way you can know the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried    `foreach(char c in que){ /*your code*/ }` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just run through the loop until the end of the string, a simple condition like this should do:

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i < que.Length )
        {
             // Your code
        }
```